# Fishpig Visual Composer Post/Page messed

Tags: wordpress, magento, fishpig

With the Fishpig Visual Composer Add-on installed the start page displays the magento homepage within a post view:
The post itself seems not to load CSS. The page shows the raw html code.

[See page here](http://webatizer.de/blog)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Installed the latest version of the [Visual Composer add-on extension for Magento WordPress Integration](http://fishpig.co.uk/magento/wordpress-integration/visual-composer/) and the problem was resolved.

Comment: Thanks! Works fine! The integration of the Visual Composer rocks the Fishpig extension.